# Touch App with QML Extension Library does not run on device or emulator, only desktop

Tags: ubuntu-touch, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to create a QML app with a C++ backend using the Ubuntu SDK (Qt Creator).

There is a template called 'App with QML Extension Library'

When I run this using the Desktop kit it compiles and runs fine.

When I run this using the UbuntuSDK for armhf (GCC ubuntu-sdk-14.04-trusty) kit it fails.

The output under general messages shows:

Could not find intltool-merge, please install the intltool package
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I don't quite understand what's wrong because the intltool package is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install intltool
```

Returns:

```
intltool is already the newest version.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with the Ubuntu SDK (qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu 3.1.1+15.04.20141117.2-0ubuntu1~0trutsty1) which is built upon Qt Creator 3.1.1.

What do I need to do to get it running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install intltool in the chroot in which you're building your binaries.

In Qt Creator, select *Tools* > *Options...* and choose the *Ubuntu* item from the list at left.  Select the *Click* tag, and then click the *Maintain* button next to the appropriate build target.  This will open a terminal with a root shell inside the chroot.  From here, use `apt-get` to install intltool and whatever else you need to compile your project.  If you have multiple chroots, repeat this with each.

Comment: This solved my problem. I'm assuming that a kit is similar to a virtual machine and that having intltool installed on the machine running Qt Creator is not enough and that it also has to be installed on the virtual machine/kit.

Comment: Yes, the kit contains a chroot ([change root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)).  Programs running within the chroot can only see the parts of the file system exposed to the chroot, so you need your tools installed there.  Although pedants will object, it's sort of like a very light-weight VM.  These chroots are set up to compile for different architectures, so you can compile for your armhf device on your x86 desktop.